# Check Is User liked or not of some specific facebook page

Tags: facebook

I tried to get whether user liked or not for some specific fan page by using following three techniques. But, all of them didn't work and gives false value or empty array as a results.

Facebook SDK is well configured and work properly. So, I have no idea what the issue on this. Please can anyone give me some suggestion for this or how can I check Is user liked or not on some specific fan page on facebook.

## 1.

`$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/<page_id>");`

`if( !empty($likes['data']) ) {`

```
`$page_like_status = "I like!";`
```

`} else {`

```
`$page_like_status = "not a fan!";`
```

`}`

## 2.

`$isFan = $facebook->api(array(`

`"method"    => "pages.isFan",`

`"page_id"   => <page_id>,`

`"uid"       => <fb_user_id>`

`));`

`if($isFan === TRUE) $tt = "I'm a fan!";`

## 3.

`if($me) {`

`$youlikeit =  $facebook->api(array(`

`"method" => "fql.query",`

`"query"  => "select uid from page_fan where uid=me() and page_id=<page_id>"`

`));`

`}`

`$youlikeit = sizeof($youlikeit) == 1 ? true : false;`

Comment: Have you asked the user for `user_likes` permission during login?

Comment: Thank you!!. :-). That was the issue.